# Why are the default private IP addresses for home networks 192.168.0.1/24?

Tags: networking

I've just finished reading up about IP addresses and subnets through this [Cisco article](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.html).

In the examples provided by the article, IP addresses seem pretty arbitrary.

This got me thinking, why are the default IP addresses for most home networks 192.168.0.1/24? Is there a reason (historic or otherwise) for the apparent convention of "192.168.0"?

Additionally, are there any implications if I decided I wanted to change my home network's IP address to something arbitrary and easier to type like 1.1.1.1/24?

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for the link. I found your response an amazing read. You may mark my question as a duplicate of that thread if you wish. Thanks again for sharing (and for taking the time to write that fantastic response).

Comment: You can do it yourself by clicking a button that should be showing above, that says something like "This solved my problem".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are *Special-Purpose IP Addresses* ([RFC 6890](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890)) and Internet addresses registered to specific owners ([IANA IPv4 Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml)). **For *private networks* you can (only) use *private addresses***:

- Private IPv4 addresses ([RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918))

  - `10.0.0.0/8` (10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255)
  - `172.16.0.0/12` (172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255)
  - `192.168.0.0/16` (192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255)
- Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses `fc00::/7` ([RFC 4193](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193))

If you configure your private network to use `1.1.1.0/24` you would be using IP addresses currently registered to the *APNIC and Cloudflare DNS Resolver project* and break connectivity with that address space, containing e.g. the [`1.1.1.1`](https://1.1.1.1/) DNS service from Cloudflare.

In the article, Cisco does not set a good example on how to use public IP addresses in examples, either. There are *IPv4 Address Blocks Reserved for Documentation* ([RFC 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737); `192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24` & `203.0.113.0/24`), but Cisco is using arbitrary addresses belonging to someone else. Don't be like Cisco.

Comment: This does not address the WHY - which is "obvious" - it is the first small (/24) network and obviously one engineer follows the next and all end up using the same private address space.

Comment: @TomTom: That's true, but also the given example `1.1.1.1/24` (instead of e.g. `192.168.123.0/23`) demonstrates the lack of understanding the private networks, not the *why*.